# Invalid Credentials

Tags: magento2, installation

I am trying to install Magento 2 in localhost via WAMPP.

I run the command

> composer install

in the magento directory and it ask me a username and a password. I use the Public and the Private Key but it returns the following message.

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>     Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/framework/magento-framework-100.1.0.0.zip', abor
>     ting.
>
> install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
>   [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts]
>   [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]
>   [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
>   [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] []...

What can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Check with creating new private and public key

Comment: I have done it but it doesn't work.